# Plot Spectral Signatures - Hyperspectral images Python

Tags: python, spectral-python

I'm working with hyperspectral images of cactus, I'm interested in plotting the wavelength.

I've been using Spectral https://www.spectralpython.net/graphics.html#spectrum-plots

I have the image in **ndarray** (MxNxB = 600x1024x768) format and I can not give it the right format to get the most out of Spectral

**What would be the right way to use the image in ndarray to graph something like this?**
[image]

or how do I transform it to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the acquisition of the image (done by a colleague). The image was permuted and did not correspond to Lambda to plot the spectrum